# запись из csv в postgre nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

собственно написал вот такой код,

```
var csv = require('csv-stream');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "pg://admin:admin@localhost:5432/labels";

// All of these arguments are optional. 
var options = {
    delimiter : ';', // default is , 
    endLine : '\n', // default is \n, 
    escapeChar : '"', // default is an empty string 
    enclosedChar : '"', // default is an empty string 

}
try {


var csvStream = csv.createStream(options);
fs.createReadStream('personss.csv').pipe(csvStream)
.on('error', function (err) {
    console.error(err);
})
.on('data', function (data) {
    // outputs an object containing a set of key/value pair representing a line found in the csv file. 
    console.log(data);

    pg.connect(conString, function (err, client, done) {
            client.query(
                'INSERT into test (firstname, lastname) from', 
        function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('data inserted');
                    }
                });

    });
});
} catch (e) {
console(e.message);
};
```

Как написать в client.query чтоб он вставлял в базу данные те строки которые были записанны в переменную data при парсере.

**Update**

```
pg.connect(conString, function (err, client, done) {
        var sql = 'INSERT into test (firstname, lastname) VALUES ("' + data.firstname + '","' + data.lastname + '")'
            client.query(sql,
        function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                console.log('data inserted' + result.data[0]);
                client.end();
                    }
                });

    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094919/how-to-import-csv-file-into-postgresql-using-node-js

Comment: https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-copy-streams#pipe-from-a-file-to-table

Comment: я не понимаю как он делает чтоб записывалось то что прошло по стриму в переменную. Начинающий я грубо говоря, маленькими шагами иду вперед

Comment: тогда читай первую ссылку, делай `forEach` по `data` и внутри вызывай `client.query`

Comment: добавил изменения, непонимаю как вызвать чтоб он записал из переменной, цикл сделал, прошел все, дальше вызываю client.query, но записи в базы нету @norbornen

Comment: в js цикл записан не правильно, в sql не insert-ятся никакие данные (хотя по первой ссылке явно показано как это делать). почитай хоть какие-то вводные книжки по этим языкам.

Comment: @norbornen как то все равно не работает, хотя сделал все полностью как по примеру. и цикл переписал

Answer (score -1):

```
 pg.connect(conString, function (err, client, done) {
    var sql = "INSERT into test (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('" + data.firstname + "','" + data.lastname + "')"
        client.query(sql,
    function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
            console.log('data inserted' + result.data[0]);
            client.end();
                }
            });

});
```

**UPDATE 1.0**

скажу одно, надо следить за кавычками